# Multi-Store in OpenCart - Config

Tags: php, opencart

I have 'website1.com' running OpenCart 2.0.1.1 and I want to set up a multi store with 'website2.com' - so that the client can manage both websites via one single admin area instance. To my understanding, I'm supposed to point 'website2.com' to use the same httpdocs location as 'website1.com'. Instead, I've set up 'website2.com' as an alias of 'website1.com' which is fine, the website loads up but what is confusing me is the config.php:

```
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.website1.com/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://www.website1.com/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/var/www/vhosts/website1.com/httpdocs/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/var/www/vhosts/website1.com/httpdocs/system/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/var/www/vhosts/website1.com/httpdocs/catalog/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/var/www/vhosts/website1.com/httpdocs/catalog/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/var/www/vhosts/website1.com/httpdocs/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/var/www/vhosts/website1.com/httpdocs/image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/var/www/vhosts/website1.com/httpdocs/system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/var/www/vhosts/website1.com/httpdocs/system/download/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', '/var/www/vhosts/website1.com/httpdocs/system/upload/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', '/var/www/vhosts/website1.com/httpdocs/system/modification/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/var/www/vhosts/website1.com/httpdocs/system/logs/');
```

Would there be any security issues if I were to change every instance of 'website1.com' to `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`? - this way, the correct directories would be loaded into the config file.

Apparently the correct way to set up multi-store is to set the domain up as a VirtualHost - but I can't understand how this would work since the `define` statements are still always going to point to the first website.

Appreciate any help!

Thanks,

Liam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multistore is handled internally, not in config.php  Just set it up as described in the **[documentation](http://docs.opencart.com/administration/multi-store/)** and it will be fine.

As for replacing your constants with `$_SERVER` globals, I don't think it would pose a security risk.  The primary use of HTTP_HOST is as a primary url setting and as a fallback when your url doesn't match any multistore.  But as I explained above, if you configure your multistore correctly you won't need to touch this.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using Plesk which doesn't allow me to follow the same documentation guidelines. My server is also running NGINX which I beleive means I'll have to set up a <VirtualHost> but I've had no success!

Comment: You would have to set up a virtual host in Apache as well so that's no different.  But I wonder about the .htaccess file.. does nginx support it?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get this working by setting up the domain as an alias!